# Custom filter for main search: how to exclude specific post_type from search results

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, search, post-type

Is there a way to use WP_Query's method, set(), in order to exclude a specific post_type from a global search.

Here was my unsuccessful attempt:

```
function _search_all($query) {  
if($query->is_search()) {
            // get rid of in the news
            $query->set('post_type__not_in', array(IN_THE_NEWS_SLUG));

    if(isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $query->set('post_type', $_GET['post_type']);
    } /*else {
        $query->set("post_type", array(FEATURES_ID, BRIEFS_ID, PRESS_RELEASES_ID));
    }*/
}
return $query;
}
add_filter("pre_get_posts", "_search_all");
```

Comment: I'd also like to point out that I cannot query all the post_types that I do want, because I use a faceted filter on the search page, and if I set all of them, they set all the faceted items checked, and by default I need them to remain unchecked before a user applies the filters.

Comment: did you try to use the `exclude_from_search => 'true'` while registering the post_type

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Hmm... Why do you think your code should work? Where did you find that `post_type__not_in`? I'm pretty sure that WP_Query has only `post_type` argument (string or array).

Comment: @MarutiMohanty Thank you. I totally overlooked that setting.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Let me point out to you my own words, "Here was my UNSUCCESSFUL ATTEMPT". =) I acknowledged that it did not work. Cheers!

Comment: @ChrisWalsh I am adding an answer. You can accept and upvote me there. Never back out from accepting credits ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the exclusion of `post_type` while registering for the post.

Use the below param to make this work

**`exclude_from_search => 'true'`**

For more details check the **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)**